# Linking an anonymous user to an Email Provider with email enumeration protection using Client SDK

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

As per the Google Cloud docs; [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection) "If you created your project on or after September 15, 2023, email enumeration protection is enabled by default."

This means that the previous way of linking an email credential to an anonymous user is now invalid.

> You can no longer use the setAccountInfo REST API to link an email/password provider to an existing user account. You can no longer use the linkWithCredential client SDK method with an EmailAuthCredential on any platform. Use the REST API signUp instead, passing the user's ID token in the idToken field and the email, password fields to link.

### PREVIOUS METHOD

```
const authLinkAccountWithEmailCredential = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    linkWithCredential(user, credential).then((userCredential) => {
      const newUser = userCredential.user;
      setUser(newUser);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("AUTH LINK ACCOUNT WITH EMAIL CREDENTIAL", error);
  }
};
```

My question is how do I now link the anonymous user to an Email Provider? - Clicking on *signUp* doesn't describe any Client SDK function for linking the user. This is for a React Native project. Using `"firebase": "^10.4.0",`

Comment: The link goes to a REST API that you can invoke from your backend.  If you are saying that you don't have a backend and need to do this entirely from your frontend, you should edit your question to make clear the constraints you have in place.

Comment: I’ve updated the question to reflect I’d like to use a Client SDK. (If possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client SDKs do not yet support this change, but according to [`firebase/firebase-js-sdk#7675`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7675), they will be updated soon.

For now, you can [disable the protection mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable) and turn it back on once the SDK is updated. You can do this via the Admin SDK or via the REST API.

**Note:** You don't need a Cloud Functions environment to install the Admin SDK, you can install it on your own system temporarily to run the commands.

---

**Edit:** Here's the code for a 1st gen Cloud Function that updates the setting. This is not an efficient way of doing it, but it does work. A similar method can be used to reenable it.

1. Deploy using `firebase deploy --only functions:disableImprovedEmailPrivacy`
2. Trigger it via its URL
3. Delete it using `firebase functions:delete disableImprovedEmailPrivacy`

```js
// index.js
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getAuth } = require('firebase-admin/auth');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

initializeApp();

exports.disableImprovedEmailPrivacy = functions.https.onRequest((_, res) => {
  getAuth()
    .projectConfigManager()
    .updateProjectConfig({
        emailPrivacyConfig: {
          enableImprovedEmailPrivacy: false
        }
    })
    .then(
      () => res.send("Done"),
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.sendStatus(500)
      }
    )
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have cloud functions for my project set up, so do I just run a function that will change the settings of the Auth? If you have an example would be much apprecated.

Comment: @DavidHenry Updated with a code sample.